# Create new Sharepoint Online calendar event using Microsoft Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, flow

Alright, I've just started with Microsoft Flow and Sharepoint Online, so please bear with me.

Anyway, the problem is that even though I seem to create an item in the sharepoint calendar (using the **Sharepoint Create Item** action), and test runs show that it was "added", the event itself isn't in the calendar.
All the information for the event is provided in the Flow itself, although I don't think that this might be the issue.

My guess is that I'm just using the wrong action, but I'm not too sure which one I'm supposed to use instead, as googling my specific problem (and a couple of general ones in the same line) hasn't given me any tangible results.

So, in short, **what Microsoft Flow action should I use, instead of the one I've already used?**

Screenshots *could* be added if necessary, although there is some sensitive information visible in the Flow, so that would have to be blacked out/blurred.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that Modern SharePoint Events Lists don't work intuitively with Flow, but with HTTP Requests it is still possible.

When Flow creates an `SP.Data.EventsListItem`, it doesn't provide a value for the property `fAllDayEvent`. This seemed to prevent the Event Item from showing up in Modern SharePoint event pages and event webparts. You can view all the properties of a list item by browsing to: `https://<site_url>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<Event_List_Name>')/items(<ID_of_the_item_just_created_by_Flow>)`

-

In order to add this property with Flow, I first create the item using the built-in "Create Item" action from flow.

Then, to add the `fAllDayEvent` property, I use the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action to update `fAllDayEvent` to be false (instead of null).

[image]

Now, when Flow creates new `EventListItems`, they show up on the Modern SharePoint events page and webparts.

You can learn more about the SharePoint List API and modifying list items here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone. Kept on getting "A type named `SP.Data.EventsListItem` could not be resolved by the model. When a model is available, each type name must resolve to a valid type."

Found out my issue by checking:

```
https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[sitename]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Events')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
```

I was using `SP.Data.EventsListItem` and should have been `SP.Data.EventsItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have hands-on experience with this scenario, my guess would be that this is caused by a missing or 'faulty' property of the list item. 
Try and fetch a list item (with flow) and check the properties and its values. Do the same for the item you have created and check if there are any differences.

Comment: Flow doesn't seem to be able to get any items from the list, but neither is it giving me the option to select the calendar's list; I have to add it manually (as a custom value). Do you think this might have something to do with it?

Comment: It's not as user friendly, but you could use the SharePoint Send HTTP request: https://www.chakkaradeep.com/2018/05/16/working-with-the-sharepoint-send-http-request-flow-action/